# Trying to setup views programatically on a loop from a template xml file

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, viewgroup, childviews

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:enabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to use this template and set it in a loop to have it dynamically reproduced.  I am able to accomplish this.  But I need to set some properties to the child views (`Button` and `TextView`) for each loop.

Here is my code so far:

```
int button_id = 0;
for (final CriticalElement e : skill.elements) {


            // add LinearLayout row
            LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.motorskills_button_template, null);
            llElementContainer.addView(LL);

            final TextView tv = (TextView) ((ViewGroup) LL).getChildAt(0);
            tv.setText(e.element);


            Button b =  (Button) ((ViewGroup) LL).getChildAt(1);
            String tag = String.valueOf(e.element_num);
            b.setTag(tag);
            b.setId(button_id);
            b.setEnabled(false);
            LL.addView(b); // issue at this line

            LL.addView(tv); 
            button_id++;
        }
```

However, I get this stacktrace:

```
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): Process: org.---.---, PID: 19019
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at org.---.---.SessionRecordMotorskillsFragment.onActivityCreated(SessionRecordMotorskillsFragment.java:125)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 08:42:10.326: E/AndroidRuntime(19019):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you don't need this line `LL.addView(b);` because button is already a child of LL

Comment: same thing for  `LL.addView(tv);`

Comment: @Dyna I just realized that as you typed it;  I am going to remove and see if it works; it was leftover from when I was doing this WITHOUT a template file.  All programatcally.

Comment: @Dyna  you can mark that as answer it appears to have worked.

Comment: I added an answer. cheers *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove this lines:

```
 LL.addView(b);
 LL.addView(tv);
```

your program will work because they are already a part of the `LinearLayout LL`